# Is there a filter to define the OG image on a given post?

Tags: multisite, facebook, open-graph

I am looking for a filter to define what image on a post sets the facebook OG image. In my case I have the image I want to use in a post meta field.

I have looked around but am unsure of the best way to handle this. Is there a core wordpress filter for this? If so I could not find one.

One solution that I looked into was through modifying the yoast seo plugin filters since we do have that plugin on our site. By default it looks to put the OG meta on the featured image which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes, it's there: [wpseo_opengraph_image](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/230e0efe8864691d65a939c839cedcdedc32592b/frontend/class-opengraph.php#L407). Are you definitely getting a different og:image tag? Can you try adding the filter earlier in the page load lifecycle, e.g. in a plugin not your theme? (I don't think that should be necessary though)

Comment: "the image lives else where in the meta data" - if I'm reading it right, it'll also use metadata key `_yoast_wpseo_opengraph-image` - see `image()` in the same file - to pick the image. But I've only skimmed class-wpseo-meta very carefully, that might be the wrong name.

Comment: Please, do not misuse moderator flags. Now you have a risen flag _against yourself_. Not good. Just file an [edit] and the system will cast a reopen vote. If the vote goes through, your question will get reopened, etc.

Comment: @kaiser Sorry did not know that!

Comment: @Rup I added it to functions.php but also into a mu plugin function. It is not working.

Answer (score 3):

The `wpseo_opengraph_image` filter can only be used to modify the existing `og:image`. Otherwise, you will need to hook into the `wpseo_opengraph` action to add a different image.

Here's an example of adding an image from a custom field on the post object (assuming you're using ACF here).

```
function my_wpseo_opengraph() {
    global $post;

    if (isset($post)) {
        $og_image = get_field('your_field_name', $post->ID);
        if ($og_image) {
            $image_url = $og_image['sizes']['large'];
            $GLOBALS['wpseo_og']->image_output($image_url);
        }
    }
}

add_action('wpseo_opengraph', 'my_wpseo_opengraph', 29);
```

Comment: It looks like you can grab it using the get_post_meta() if you have it in a basic custom field and don't have ACF, as long as you are setting the global wpseo_og parameter?

Comment: Yep! `$GLOBALS['wpseo_og']->image_output($image_url);` is the only important part... The rest was just for context.

Comment: Thanks a lot @smilly92

Comment: This is no longer working. `wpseo_opengraph` is deprecated.